# how to deal withenddate null value when you do DATEADD(dd,1, s.endDate))

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have startDate and endDate but I find problem some endDate has null value when I do  get value between startDate and endDate +1 I get 0 value because of endDate is null

```
Select* form s where AND (GETDATE() >= s.startDate AND GETDATE() <= DATEADD(dd,1, s.endDate))
```

the DATEADD will return null because endDate is null.just I want to ask when I search for range hoe cvan I deal the endDate has null value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Select* form s where AND (GETDATE() >= s.startDate AND 
GETDATE() <=  DATEADD(dd,1, COALESCE(s.endDate,s.startDate))
```

Comment: Just as an optimization idea: don't use GETDATE() directly in your WHERE clause. Create a variable, set it to GETDATE() and use the variable. That way, the GETDATE() function only needs to be called once per query (fast) instead of twice per row (slow).

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @nowStart DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @nowEnd DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, -1, @nowStart)

Select * 
from s 
where (@nowStart >= s.startDate 
      and (s.endDate is null or @nowEnd <= s.endDate))
```